# Use Vector Space Model instead of BM25 in Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene

How can I change the scoring in Lucene and use Vector Space Model instead of BM25?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you looking for the old TF/IDF scoring, or do you want a more plain VSM?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to create a program that check the credibility of the text  using Lucene. The credibility of the text depend on the scores. When I used BM25, I noticed that there is no threshold score that can be used to determine if the text is credible or not. Also there is no score limit to determine if the text is highly similar or not.  So I would like to try VSM.

Comment: What would "text is credible" mean? That's a very broad sense of a word - are you sure you're looking for similarity algorithms and not NLP?

Comment: Credible means the text is fact. Yes I want to solve the problem using information retrieval not NLP.

Comment: How do you define a fact in your case?

Comment: If the similarity between the entered text for searching and the document collections are high, then the text is a fact or credible. If the similarity is low then it is not credible text. But I do not how can I do that in Lucene

Comment: So how do you define "similarity is high" or "similarity is low"?

Comment: I do not know, I cannot do it with BM25 :/. I searched for a solution to do it but I did not find a solution.

Comment: You're going to at least understand what problem you're trying to solve before trying to find a solution for it - the actual scale of scoring isn't the actual issue for your problem, and before moving further, you should try to define why a VSM (which BM25 and TFIDF are implementations of, with different weighting based on recurrence and term / field length etc.) would help solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the algorithm used to score documents by setting the Similarity with [IndexWriterConfig.setSimilarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html#setSimilarity-org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity-) and [IndexSearcher.setSimilarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#setSimilarity-org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity-). Note, you should be using the same similarity implementation when writing and searching, and will generally need to reindex any time you want to try a different similarity.

There are a number of [Similarity implementations](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/package-summary.html) available out of the box.

Lucene's old default similarity is [ClassicSimilarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ClassicSimilarity.html), which is a TFIDF (ie. VSM) implementation as [documented here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

It will, however, not accomplish what you are looking for based on your comment. It also will not provide you a meaningful way to normalize scores, or establish useful thresholds and scores do not have upper limits.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will do that and see. .. What do you think I have to do to  establish useful thresholds ?

Comment: Don't really know your actual requirements, but my general advice is *rethink what you are trying to do.* If you want your minimum results to be guaranteed to be more relevant, consider constructing your queries more carefully to not get weak matches.

Answer (score 1):

To use a different similarity set the similarity in the `indexSearcher` using:

```
IndexSearcher indexSearcher;

IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDirectory);
indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

...

indexSearcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());    //default in newer versions and above
//or
indexSearcher.setSimilarity(new ClassicSimilarity());
//or any other similarity
```